# Converting Yearly Salary to Weekly in Swift

Tags: swift, math

I am trying to convert yearly salary to weekly. So, 312,000 yearly salary should come out as $6000 weekly.

Here is my formula which is not giving the desired result:

```
weeklySalary = (yearlySalary / 12) / 4
```

Also, how can I convert yearly to hourly!

Comment: `(312000 / 12) / 4 = 6500` ...? And converting to hourly, divide weekly by the number of hours worked in a week (typically 37.5 or 40). *See answer below, noting there are not 4 weeks per month, so divide yearly by 52 rather than 48.

Comment: This only makes sense if the payroll system calculates weekly amounts.  Mine pays bi-weekly, so there are 26 paychecks per year.  Others do bi-monthly: 15th and last day of the month, so there are 24 paychecks per year.  I weep for our collective mathematical ability that such a simple unit conversion requires a question on SO.

Comment: Should this question be reworded to "How many weeks are there in a year?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 52 weeks in a year, so `weeklySalary = yearlySalary / 52`. If you want hourly, there are 40 working hours in a week, so `hourlySalary = weeklySalary / 40`.